# How to view table data in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

AWS Console seems to indicate my tables have some data from my test put_item() calls, but I would like to actually *see* the data. Is there a means to do this in AWS Console? I've read something on AWS Explorer that can be installed as a plugin to eclipse or visual studios, but I'm a PHP developer who doesn't use Eclipse, so it seems silly to install a whole IDE just to ensure the correct data is being entered.

How can I check the data in my DynamoDB tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[UPDATE]
Amazon just launched "Explore Table" for DynamoDB in the AWS Management Console.

---

If you are using Visual Studio or Eclipse, you can use the [AWS Explorer](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/#explorer) to see all of your tables and data.

In Eclipse it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of AWS Explorer in Eclipse]

Comment: How to view tables in Local Dynamo DB ?

Comment: @VijayBalkawade For local dynamo db I have used this for localhost port 8000 (aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000)

Answer (score 0):

Search and just visit DynamoDB and then click Explore items on the left side

[image]